# Thoughtful way to show Klein-4 group is a subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am learning Klein-4 group $G:=\{id,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$.

It is easy to show that every element in $G$ is the inverse of itself, as disjoint permutations commutes.

So, to show $G<S_4$, we only need to show $G$ is closed under composition. The obvious way to show that is to compute each composition. Is there any more thoughtful way to prove the closure under composition?

Comment: Compute one composition and observe the other cases are similar

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov How? I computed $(12)(34)(13)(24)=(14)(32)$ But I can not see how it is related to other computations. Thank you.

Comment: oh thank you. got it @VáclavMordvinov

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Alternatively, $K_4 \cong C_2 \times C_2 \cong S_2 \times S_2 \hookrightarrow S_4$.

This gives the subgroup $K=\{id,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$ of $S_4$, not the one in the question, but it is clear that $K$ is closed under composition.